# to capture packets with options like -i interface, -o open file, etc using pyshark and python

Tags: python, performance, tcp, udp

review my code if possible. I am making network packet capture using pyshark and python. if possible give me some feedback about the code and help to make it better.

````
!/usr/bin/python

import argparse
import pyshark
import time
import re as regex


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--interface', metavar=" ", type=str, required = True, help = 'To specify the interface ')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', required = False, action = 'store_true', help = 'To print the all layer of packet')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', metavar=' ', help = 'To capture and save the pcap in a file')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--protocol', metavar=' ', help= 'To capture packet using ptotocl filter')
parser.add_argument('-u', '--udp', action = 'store_true', help = 'To capture udp packet only')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--tcp', action = 'store_true', help = 'To capture tcp packet only')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--count', metavar=' ',default=1,  help = 'To capture limited number of packet')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.protocol:
   capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=args.interface, display_filter=args.protocol)


elif args.udp:
   capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=args.interface, bpf_filter='udp')

elif args.tcp:
   capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=args.interface, bpf_filter='tcp')

else:
   capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface=args.interface, output_file=args.output)
   capture.sniff(packet_count = args.count)

packet_list = []

for packet in capture.sniff_continuously():
    if 'IP Layer' in str(packet.layers):
        protocol = regex.search(r'(Protocol:)(.*)',str(packet.ip))
        protocol_type = protocol.group(2).strip().split(' ')[0]
       # proto = protocol_type
    localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())) 
    proto = protocol_type
    src_addr = packet.ip.src
    dst_addr = packet.ip.dst
    length = packet.length
    print (localtime, '\t' , proto, '\t' ,src_addr, '\t', dst_addr, '\t' , length)
    if args.verbose:
       print(packet.show())

```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately this question is _off-topic_ because this site is for reviewing **working** code. Please [take the tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up at our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). When the code works then feel free to [edit] the post to include it for a review.

Comment: This comes per “_I want to add a feature to open the pcap file in my packet capture but I am not getting any idea. please help me to add this feature in this code below_” if that statement is removed then it would be more on topic.

Comment: thank you for recommendation

Answer (score 1):

Nice, I'm glad you use pyshark so much that
it's useful to customize it a bit.

High level advice: Use functions!
Everything here is at module level,
and we could reduce global variable coupling
by pushing most of it down into various functions.

---

```
!/usr/bin/python
```

nit, typo: I'm sure you meant `#!/usr/...`.

Consider leaving it as just `#! python`,
to exploit `$PATH` in the case where a venv is active.
I usually write `#! /usr/bin/env python`,
so that even crazy and ancient operating systems
will obey `$PATH`.

---

```
import re as regex
```

Wow, can't say I've ever seen aliasing used
to make a module's name longer.
More power to you, if you find it clearer.

---

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The whole parser thing is lovely,
you're using it in exactly the right way.
But notice that it took seven lines to add
the various arguments, and I'm sure another
one will be added next month.
So I usually banish such a stanza into a helper,
and then assign

```
args = get_parser().parse_args()
```

Then again, this *whole thing* plus the following
really belongs within a `def main():`, so variables like `parser`
don't wind up polluting the top level global namespace.

---

```
if args.protocol:
```

Sooo, I just encouraged you to write a helper.
But now I'm going to about-face on that and
say `parser` is a lovely builtin library,
but `$ pip install typer` is even better.

https://pypi.org/project/typer

I used to create arg parser objects all the time.
But nowadays we have optional type annotations,
and it's much more straightforward to write this:

```
def main(interface: str, protocol: str, verbose: bool = False):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(main)
```

and then instead of `args.protocol` just reference `protocol`.

(I left out some args in the example, and
maybe help text is important. You decide.)

---

```
packet_list = []
```

Looks like a leftover unused variable
that you meant to delete before submitting snapshot for review.

If you do intend to keep it,
consider renaming to plural `packets`
to indicate it's a container,
avoiding the clunky `_list` suffix.

---

Thank you for the r-string here, it's a good habit to be in, kudos.

```
        protocol = regex.search(r'(Protocol:)(.*)', str(packet.ip))
```

This is within a loop.
We are re-compiling a regex each time through,
but the source string is a constant so the regex won't be changing.
Recommend you hoist the constant expression outside of the loop.
It's no big deal one way or the other.

```
    protocol_re = regex.compile(r'(Protocol:)(.*)')
    for packet in ... :
        ...
        protocol = protocol_re.search(str(packet.ip))
```

Two more small items:

nit: No need for a capturing group on that constant `Protocol:` text.

Prefer `r'^Protocol:(.*)'`, if it appears at start of line.
That way on a mismatched line we're not scanning the whole
thing for capital P. The `^` caret anchor lets the regex engine
abandon immediately if the line doesn't start with `Protocol`.

---

Overall?

Functions are your friend. Use them. Write small blocks
of code that are visible all-at-once in a single window
with no scrolling. More code than that? Break it up!

Remaining issues are minor.

LGTM, ship it!

Comment: thank you for the comment and recommendations